# Что можно писать на C++?

Tags: c++

Вот говорят, что в гугле/яндексе очень много кода на C, а мне интересно, что именно они там пишут? Какие  библиотеки, фреймворки используют?

Хочется писать что то кроме консольных приложений на С++ и желательно под юникс. В какую сторону посмотреть? (только не Qt - не понравился)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У яндекса есть своя реализация движка обработчика регулярных выражений, по слухам самый быстрый, правда скорость увеличили за счет отсечения некоторого ненужного функционала.
Google активно использует mysql, но не обычную версию, которая столь популярна, а очень сильно переписанная, в итоге базы данных там получаются плоские, что тоже сильно увеличивает скорость ее работы, MySQL написана на C++ соответственно и патчи тоже на нем же.

Оба поисковика активно используют Apache, он написан и на C++, и просто на C. Соответственно тоже сильно допилены под свои нужды, многие модули для баз и серверов пишутся на С++/С.

Это тока малая подборка, может кто еще чего интересного подкинет?